# How to design this?

Tags: website-design, page-layout, design-principles, interface-design, website-templates

Image 1 is what i had first, obviously a bèta version of the design as this bar with buttons still needs to be designed / given layout.

Image 2 is my attempt at (re)designing it.

Image 3 is to explain further what i need, this bar will be used to display both a status, and display some buttons, this is why i started to align buttons on the right side of the bar, adding also a tabbed menu there.

Now problem is i really want to make this look neat, but i'm new to designing and have no idea how to make this work, as you can see obviously image 2 isn't really good for a finished product.

Any tips, visual design examples, redesigns, anything? would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Hi there, could you give a little more indication as  to what the purpose of the end product is. Is it going to be a spreadsheet/a travel app etc. As though subjective these things all have their own design philosophies so it's hard to give feedback with little indication of what it would be for.

Comment: @JennaDesign the white space underneath the bar will be used for two purpsoses, the side purpose being displaying a table as you can see here. The main purpose being some kind of drawing board or canvas, through the menu on th left u will be able to select images and drag and drop them on the canvas, being able to snap them together, align them, or export the image to a file (PHP,XML,..).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @Firebirdz I'm afraid that I do not know what you want the design of the end product to be therefore I can't help you with 'how to' design it. Sorry I couldn't help more, hopefully somebody else can, or I catch up with exactly what you want! Good luck with your project.

Comment: `delete` and `import` under the `export` tab makes little sense conceptually.

Comment: "How do I make this look neat?" Is not a viable question the community can supply objectionable and votable answers to.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to GD Firebirdz.  In regards to your question it maybe considered by some as off-topic but I will try to give you some advise on how to make a better design.

- Your whole design is Monochromatic:

> Monochromatic colours are all the colors (tints, tones, and shades) of
>   a single hue.

- You're not utilizing color very well and it's hard to distinguish
  between what is a priority and what is not.
- Your table is very crammed and does not utilize whitespace very well.  I would suggest separating the tables with space.
- Change the colors on your table number sequence because at this moment all your typography is the same color.
- The table colors are too harsh and take away from the data.

### Some examples of quality tables you may want to consider:

Notice in the table below each row is designed in either a grey or white and the actual table is a very light grey.

[image]

This table utilizes color in the header and adds a subtle glow to the selected row and changes the header of the selected:

[image]

This table utilizes simplicity and may fit you best.  Notice the subtle colors are not hard or strong but warm.  They still allow the information to be displayed in a uniform manner but the table itself isnt harsh to the eyes:

[image]